# How to include taglibs in the WAR file to make sure it can run on machine without internet access?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, war

I have a web app built with Java and Spring.

In my JSPs there are lines like this which appear to be referencing tag libraries that are located on the web.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Sometimes the web app will be running on a machine on an internal network without internet access.

In that case, does this mean that the web app won't work because it won't be able to see `java.sun.com` and `www.springframework.org`?

If so ... how do I include these taglibs in the WAR file so the application is complete self contained?